# Modifying a window's textbox control's text

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, text, controls

Case in point : I've got a handle to a window (for instance, using the getForegroundWindow() API function). This window's got a textbox (possibly a richtext control). Would it be possible to modify the textbox's text through an Windows API call ? More specifically, I'd like to replace its text with some of my own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you have the handle to the parent window, you need to get the handle to the editcontrol.

If the editcontrol has a known, consistent identifier, use [GetDlgItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645481%28VS.85%29.aspx) to get its HWND.  Otherwise you will need to resort to [FindWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633500%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Once you have the HWND of the editcontrol, you can use [SendMessage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950%28VS.85%29.aspx) to send a [WM_SETTEXT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632644%28VS.85%29.aspx) message it.  For rich text controls, use the [EM_SETTEXTEX](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774284%28VS.85%29.aspx) message.

Comment: That has same effect as a SetWindowText() call - Only the title bar's text is changed.

Comment: I've just confirmed - The target is a RichText control.

Comment: For rich text controls, use EM_SETTEXTEX http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb774284%28VS.85%29.aspx